# How to show next month in Vue Datepicker if current date is end of current month?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue Datepicker to display a calendar. My problem is if the current date is end of month,
the calendar still shows all date of current month which set to disable to select.

If this is the case, I want to display all date of next month for user to select.

How can I do to get result?

Answer (score 0):

After read Vue Datepicker document, I found that I should use `start-date` props and set it to below

```
startDate: {
    type: [Date, String],
    default: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 *24),
    required: false,
},
```

It worked for my case.